# time complexity of an algorithm( pseudocode)

Tags: time, complexity-theory

```
prod=1;
Nfour= sqrt(n) * sqrt(n);
    For k=1 to Nfour do
        If K mod sqrt(n)=0 then
            for j=1 to k do
                if j mod sqrt(n)=0 then
                    for m=1 to j do
                        prod=prod *4
```

How can I calculate time complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the above code we have 3 nested for loops which will take n^3 complexity as they are nested and remaining operations take constant time.

This resource might be helpful - 1- http://bigocheatsheet.com/
                                 2- [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)